# Is the term "Particle physics in cancer treatment" correct?

Tags: prepositions

I have to give a talk about how methods of particle physics are applied to cancer therapy. Is the title "Particle physics *in* cancer treatment" or "Particle physics *for* cancer treatment" correct ?

Comment: It should be “Particle physics in cancer treatment”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use "Particle physics **in** cancer treatment". The `in` here indicates that you're describing the field that the subject is being discussed in.

`For` brings strange connotations that don't quite match. It indicates a purpose, and using it would indicate that you're discussing physics that are intended and specific to cancer treatment, which likely isn't what you want to say, because the laws of physics don't have intention/purpose or or work differently in different professions.

**Conclusion**- Use "Particle physics **in** cancer treatment".

Answer (score 1):

> Particle physics **in** cancer treatment.

*in* means that particle physics is a component *part* of cancer treatment. Cancer treatment includes this and other activities.

> Particle physics **for** cancer treatment.

*for* indicates purpose. Particle physics exists for the *purpose of* treating cancer.
But as written this is worded strangely. Better would be:

> Usage of particle physics **for** treating cancer.

A better example where *to* works might be:

> We are accepting donations **for** cancer treatment.